# Thymeleaf Fragments: How to pass String to Fragment to be used as onchange method

Tags: html, thymeleaf, onchange

I am having an issue with the relationship between my Thymeleaf content file and fragment file that it uses. From the content file, I am passing many parameters to the fragment that are successfully rendered. However, one parameter that isn't working is a string that I'm passing that is to be used as an onchange method. The error I'm getting is that `Method call: theMethod() cannot be found...`  Here is a simplified snippet of the content file that I'll call content.html:

```
<div>
   <span th:replace="inputs::myInput('idExample', 'theMethod()')"></span>
</div>
```

And then here is the simplified snippet of the fragment file that I'll call fragment.html:

```
<span th:fragment="myInput(id, onchange)">
   <select th:id="${id}" th:onchange="${__${onchange}__}">
      ...
      ...
      ...
   </select>
</span>
```

Now, theMethod() is defined in a .js file that I have tried including directly as a src in both the content.html and fragment.html files, and it still gives the same error that the method call can't be found. And even if I directly define a theMethod() function in content.html and/or fragment.html, it STILL gives the same error. So I'm thinking maybe the structure of what I have in the `th:onchange` could be incorrect but not sure. For example maybe the `${__${}__}` structure is wrong because I'm not that familiar with the detailed Thymeleaf syntaxes out there.

Answer (score 2):

`${__${onchange}__}` is trying to run `${theMethod()}` as Thymeleaf code -- which is having the Thymeleaf interpreter try to run the java function `theMethod()`.

That being said, if you change it to `th:onchange="${onchange}"`, you probably ran into the error `Only variable expressions returning numbers or booleans are allowed in this context, any other datatypes are not trusted in the context of this expression`

Thymeleaf ***really*** doesn't want you try and build JavaScript expressions and output them in html attributes because of the security vulnerabilities that can happen because of this.  They typical way to solve problems like these is to pass function arguments to `th:data-*` attributes and then have hardcoded JavaScript like this:

```
<select th:data-id="${id}" th:data-name="${name}" onchange="onChange(this.getAttribute('id'), this.getAttribute('name'))">
```

That may or may not be directly applicable here -- so there is no easy way to solve your problem without restructuring the way you are handling `onChange` events.